# Trying to update a mongodb document field via pug/node.js button click

Tags: node.js, mongodb, button, onclick, pug

This is a document from my todo mongodb:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5a1e96f856f24c43b886eb54"),
"title" : "Drink coffee",
"note" : "Tomorrow morning",
"open" : true,
"duedate" : "2017-12-03"
```

This is the pug code that populates a todo list page

```
each todo in todolist
   if todo.open
      div
         a(href="#") #{todo.title}
      div
         p(style='white-space:pre;')
          |   #{todo.note}
          |   Due: #{todo.duedate}
          button(id="doneButton") Done
```

The above works fine. The todo page displays all todo items as expected.

What I want to do:
When user clicks on 'Done' button, I want to update that particular document to "open": false. 
(I want to do this onclick, and not by loading the item on a new edit page with an edit button. When todo list page reloads, that todo item is removed from the list. I do not want to delete the document as I need to archive it later on.)

So my questions are:

- How do I code the 'Done' button on the pug page so that it gets
  associated with the particular document that needs to be updated?
- How do I structure the POST code on my index.js so that it listens for
  the button click and performs the relevant document update?

**UPDATE**

OK, so I don't know enough to understand kentor's reply (but thank you anyway!). I did a bit of research though and some copying and pasting, and I have moved the problem a couple of steps forward - I hope.

New pug code:

```
each todo in todolist
   if todo.open
      a(href="#") #{todo.title}
      p #{todo.note}
      p Due: #{todo.duedate}
      form#form_update_item(name="updateitem", method='post', action='/updateitem')
      input#input_name(type="hidden", placeholder="", name="_id", value="#{todo._id}")
      button(type="submit") Done
```

index.js code

```
router.post('/updateitem', function(req, res) {
  var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;

  var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId;

  var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/tododb';

  MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("can't connect", err);
    }
    else {
      console.log('Connected to server. Woohoo!');

      var collection = db.collection('todolist');

      collection.findOneAndUpdate(
        {"title": "Make smoothie"}, 
        {
        $set: {
          "open": false
          }
        }, 
        function(err, result) {
          if (err) {
              console.log(err);
          } else {
              res.redirect("todolist");
          }
          db.close(); 
      });
    }
  });
});
```

What happens now:

- On button click, doc with title "Make Smoothie" changes to "open": false. So button triggers the change I want. Bang! But this is only a partial solution to help me isolate the problem.

What I still need:

- On button click, I want the doc's ID whose button was clicked to replace {"title": "Make smoothie"} so that the "open": false change can be made. Something like {_id: "doc ID coming from button blah blah"}.

**UPDATE 2**

Discovered that I was using Jade syntax not Pug, so instead of this

```
value="#{todo._id}
```

I should be using

```
value=todo._id
```

So now index.js can console.log the ID the Pug form is passing. Last challenge is to use that ID to change the corresponding mongodb document as described above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I finally solved it**

Last step, I replaced

```
{"title": "Make smoothie"}
```

with

```
{"_id": ObjectId(req.body._id)}
```

and sure enough, every time I click on a button, the server updates the corresponding document's "open": false

Answer (score -1):

You could just attach a data attribute to the HTML button like this:

```
button(id="doneButton", data-id=todo._id) Done
```

Then you would just attach an event listener to this button and send a POST request containing this data-id. Using Jquery it could look like this:

```
.script
  $('#doneButton').on("click", function (element) {
    var data = $(this).data("id");
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "your-url",
      data: { todoId: data },
      success: responseHandler
    })
  })
```